# Finding the optimal adjacency matrix

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, semidefinite-programming, adjacency-matrix

**Notation**: Let $\mathbf{A} \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ be the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph. Let $\mathbf{D}$ be the degree matrix of this graph and let $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{D} - \mathbf{A}$ be the Laplacian matrix. The normalized Laplacian matrix $\mathbf{L}_N$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{L}_N := \mathbf{D}^{-1/2} (\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{A}) \mathbf{D}^{-1/2} = \mathbf{D}^{-1/2} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{D}^{-1/2}.
\end{equation}

Given an initial adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}^0$, a constant $b > 0$ and a matrix $\mathbf{Z} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, consider the following two optimization problems

\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{A}} \quad \mathsf{Tr} \left( \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{L} \mathbf{Z}^\top \right) \quad \text{s.t.}\quad \left\| \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}^0 \right\|_2 \leq b \tag{OP$_1$}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\min_{\mathbf{A}} \quad \mathsf{Tr} \left(\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{L}_N\mathbf{Z}^\top \right) \quad \text{s.t.}\quad \left\| \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}^0 \right\|_2 \leq b \tag{OP$_2$}
\end{equation}

where $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the $2$-norm and $\mathsf{Tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace. Which type do these optimization problems belong to? Any potential solution algorithms?

Comment: Your objectives do not depend on $A$, so they are fixed. That is probably not intentional?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek L depends on A.

Comment: That is not clear from your notation because you write it as if you start with a fixed $A^0,D^0,L^0,L^0_N$ all depending on the same initial graph. So please fix the notation. Now it is not clear what is fixed and what depends on $A$.

Comment: Notation fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The first problem is an SOCP (second order cone problem). The objective is linear and there is one second order cone constraint. (Can also be seen as a QP, quadratic problem). There are efficient solvers for that. The second one looks much harder and in particular does not seem convex.

Comment: Sorry, I quickly assumed that by L2-norm you mean Frobenius norm. Then it is an SOCP. If you mean the spectral norm then it is an SDP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a direction. I will investigate more.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Undirected.

Comment: @beyondzk In that case, shouldn't the adjacency matrix be symmetric?

Comment: @beyondzk Isn't ${\bf D} = {\bf A} {\bf 1}_n$?

Comment: @beyondzk Usually, knowns are denoted using the first letters of the Latin alphabet.  I would choose $\bf C$ instead  of $\bf Z$

Comment: $\| \cdot \|_2$ denote the Frobenius norm or the spectral norm?

Comment: If you improve the question, I will vote for reopening